# assign instance of child class from parent variable to child variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent class, called MyClass.  It has two children defined as:

```
export class MyChildFirst extends MyClass {...}
export class MyChildSecond extends MyClass {...}
```

Every instance of MyClass belongs to one of the two children.  I then have an array of MyClass.  I am looping through the array, and I want to assign those MyClass instances that belong to MyChildSecond to an array of MyChildSecond.

```
var bigArray = new Array<MyClass>();
// ...
// populate that array
// ...
var smallArray = new Array<MyChildSecond>();
for (var element of bigArray) {
   if (element.constructor.name === 'MyChildSecond') {
      smallArray[smallArray.length] = element;
   }
}
```

However, this doesn't work, because even though the code ensures that only MyChildSecond would be assigned to the array, it is viewing 'element' as a MyClass and so can not assign it to a variable that holds MyChildSecond.  How can I implement this?

Comment: your code looks fine and it works here: https://plnkr.co/edit/grZj8tMKfkQ5Nixzh7Q8?p=preview

Comment: It is not working within the context of my Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof` with classes in TypeScript.

```
var smallArray = bigArray.filter(
                   (element)=>element instanceof MyChildSecond
                 ) as MyChildSecond[];
```

Comment: this creates an array of MyClass that contains only those elements of bigArray that are instances of MyChildSecond.  I need it in the form of an array of MyChildSecond, rather than an array of MyClass that only contains MyChildSecond.  This means that I can not access elements that are unique to MyChildSecond, which is my goal.

Comment: @chodobaggins that doesn't sound right to me. I've updated my answer to clarify the type issue.

Comment: for whatever reason this is returning an empty array, I am really puzzled

Comment: I think it is because even though they elements of the array ARE MyChildFirst and MyChildSecond, they are stored as MyClass, so they fail the instanceof condition.